# $V$ is a set of polynomials, find whether its a subspace the explicit form of elements and dimension of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let  $V$ be the set of all real polynomials $p$ of degree at most $2$ satisfying $p(0) = p(1),$ i.e. polynomials with the same values at $x = 0$ and $x = 1.$

$a)$ Use the subspace theorem to decide whether the above set $V$ is a real vector
space with the usual operations.

$b)$ Find the explicit  form of all polynomial $p\in V$ , that is, determine all $a, b, c \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $p(x) = a + bx + cx^2$ satisfies $p(0) = p(1).$

$c)$ Determine the dimension of the space $V$.

I  believe I have found an answer for part $a)$ by proving the set $V$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.

No idea for $b)$ and $c)$. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: When you say it's not closed under addition, you are saying that you have found $p$ and $q$ in $V$ such that $p+q$ is not in $V$. I'd like to see them. Anyway, c) makes no sense if $V$ isn't a vector space, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your assumption we have: $p(0)=a$ and $p(1)=a+b+c$ so from $p(0)=p(1)$
we conclude tat $a=a+b+c$ the   $b=-c$ so the condition for required polynomials is $b=-c$ so the polynomials have the for m $a+bx-bx^2$
$V$is $2$ dimentinal vector space.
Certainly $V$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.$$ If \ p_1(0)=p_1(1) \  and \ p_2(0)=p_2(1) \ then (p_1+p_2)(0)=(p_1+p_2)(1)\\ \lambda p_1(0)=\lambda p_1(1) $$

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting me on my mistake for part a! Still not 100% sure on how to work out part b? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are welcome,  as you see I have write the explicit form of elements as $a+bx=bx^2$ note that $b=-c$ or $c=-b$

Comment: Ahhh okay I follow, so then for part c, do I have to find the basis in order to find the dimension or is the answer a lot simpler than that? Again thank you, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: loosely speaking we can say that there are to coefficient $a,b$ so the dimention is $2$

Comment: You are an absolute legend! Thank you once again