# About the dimension of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ be the vector space, under the usual operations, of real polynomials that are of degree at most 3. Let $W$ be the subspace of all polynomials $p(x)$ in $V$ such that $p(0)=p(1)=p(-1)=0$. Then $dim(V)+dim(W)$ is?

Apparantly, the dimension of $V$ is 4, and the condition gives me $a=c=0$ for polynomials like $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$. Thus, I thought the dimension of $W$ is 2 for polynomials of the form $bx+dx^3$ and $dim(V)+dim(W)=6$. However, the answer says that $dim(V)+dim(W)=5$. I examined my answer and the only missing point is that actually $b=-d$, but I don't quite understand how it made the dimension be 1 instead of 2?

Comment: @geetha290krm I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709817/v-is-a-set-of-polynomials-find-whether-its-a-subspace-the-explicit-form-of-el), and it seems to be the case. I guess I don't understand how the dimension of polynomials works?

Comment: The dimension of $V$ in that link is $2$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Now I am confused. The dimension of $V$ in that link is polynomials of the form $a+bx-bx^2$ which is 2, but how here the dimension of $W$ with polynomials of the form $bx-bx^3$ is 2 as well(if my answer is correct)?

Comment: I am sorry, in the present question dimension of $W$ is $1$ so $5$ is the correct answer. $W$  is spanned by the single polynomial $x-x^{3}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm So if I understand correctly, the dimension of polynomials only depends on the coefficients as the linear independent vectors are monomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$b=-d$ means that every polynomial in $W$ is a multiple of a real number and the polynom $x^3-x$. That's what it means to be a 1-dimensional real vector space, everything can be expressed as a product of an arbitrary real number and **one** element of the vector space.

You might be thinking that the general term $p(x) = dx^3-dx$ of a polynomial in $W$ contains both $x$ and $x^3$, so $W$ should have dimension 2. That likely comes from the fact that you think of terms like $x^n$ as **the** basis of polynomial vector spaces.

But those terms can be replaced by many others, there are many bases for $V$. For example $1, 2x-1, -x^2+3x-5, x^3-x$ also form a basis of $V$. As you can see, you only need one element of that basis to form $W$, not two.

Another way to see that $x$ and $x^3$ are not basis elements of $W$ is to realize that **neither is in $W$ at all**! As you realized after being given the solution, the additional constraint of $b=-d$ cannot be ignored, because obviously neither $x$ nor $x^3$ have a root at $x=\pm1$.

A third way to easily "see" that $W$ has dimension $1$ is to realize that the general polynom in $W, (dx^3-dx$) has only one free parameter ($d$), vs. the 4 free parameters for the general polynom in $V, a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$. That works as long as the parameters are really free (and there is no "hidden" conditions like $b=-d$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!